# Insert CLOB via createNativeQuery JPA methor into ORACLE without 32766 character limit

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, clob

Environment:

- DB: Oracle
- Spring: 3.1.2
- Hibernate: 3.6.0

Problem:

When I try to execute this code with string bigger then 32766 character I'm getting exception:

```
Query updateQuery = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("Insert into CLOB_TEST (ID,CLOB_COLUMN)values(120001,?)");
updateQuery.setParameter(1, "CLOB VALUE");
updateQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Exception:

```
SQLException: setString can only process strings of less than 32766
```

Requirements:

- I need to use entityManager.createNativeQuery method
- cannot use ORM because I do not have static mappings
- I need to insert/update CLOB data without character 32766 limit
- I need JPA transaction management

Workaround:

I was able to overcome this limitation by using PreparedStatement received from native oracle connection but then I'm unable to manage transactions with @Transaction annotation because I'm ommiting entityManager.

Question:

Is there a way to overcome this limitation without loosing JPA transaction management capabilities ?

Comment: how about using the JPA implementation for what it is intended for? have an entity that maps on to this table and then define a field as @Lob and it does it for you

Comment: See mine answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306922/managing-java-clob-with-jboss-and-tomcat. Even if you are trying to insert the CLOB, it must be 1st created inside the database and then fetched FROM database. So it much be OUT parameter even if want to write in it.

Comment: Neil Stockton: Unfortunatelly I don't have possiblity to create static entity mapping - this information is dynamic in my system

Comment: there are some JPA implementations that allow a class to be dynamically defined, and used as an "entity"